# Can you have one fragment follow another fragment?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Is the sentence below grammatically correct?

> The teenagers drove to the party, some arriving in sports cars, others
>   arriving in limousines.

I know that the sentence ended after the "**some arriving in sports cars**" phrase. But, can I place another clause "**others...limousines**" behind the first phrase after a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's perfectly natural and grammatical. In fact it's quite a sophisticated and streamlined way of informing your readers that two separate groups,  or actually *how* the two groups,  arrived at the party. Well done!

The reason it works is because you now have a list of two things separated by a comma:

> some arriving in sports cars, others arriving in limousines

In fact you don't have to stop with two in the list; you could add as many as you want:

> some arriving in sports cars, others arriving in limousines, yet others arriving by Uber, yet again others arriving by horse & carriage, and others even on foot.

But hopefully you can see that using such an extended list becomes tedious to read and the reader will soon be crying out for a change in style. Which is why I said that your version is sophisticated: the reader is given just long of a list to appreciate the fine style it exhibits.

Comment: This is a relief to know that sentence makes sense. Thank you!!!

Comment: Would taking the comma out and replacing it with an "and" also work? 

The women soon disperse, some entering the shallow water at the beach and others venturing out onto the rocks to access deeper waters.

Comment: Yes. That's perfect also.